# Could Unlocked Package installation delete or update Record Types of existing records?

Tags: salesforcedx, record-type, package-install, unlocked-package

I have an object A with record type a1 and a2. I made an unlocked package and installed it to production org. After a few days, the client comes with some other changes and I made another version of the unlocked package and installed it to production. Here is what happened after it:-

- Record type value from all **old records** (created before
  package installation) gets empty for object A.
- New Records are creating perfectly and have record type values.
- Last modified date on old records are not the same as the package installation date.
- In the **setup audit trail** there is no evidence of record type change.

I am not able to figure out how and why record type value from old records get removed and that is too without a change in last modified date.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you uninstall the old version first?

Comment: Would he have to uninstall first? I mean it looks like it’s the same package.

Comment: No, I have not uninstalled it. I have upgraded the package . @sfdcfox