# Upgrade of Unlocked Package changed RecordTypeId of existing records

Tags: salesforcedx, record-type, unlocked-package, platform-bug, 2gp-ama

I have an Unlocked SFDX Package with a `CustomObject__c` and two Record Types `RTypeA` and `RTypeB`.

The object and the two types have existed in the package before my update. Before the upgrade all records of this type had either the one or the other RecordType.

**The strange thing is that after my package** upgrade all records lost their RecordType (meaning `RecordTypeId = null`).

It's **also strange** that the CreatedDate of the two previously existing RecordTypes has changes to the date of the package upgrade. I don't get that.

What did I do wrong or is this a platform bug?

Comment: You're the [second person](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/286675/2984) I know of to report this. Appears there may be something going on. I'll ask.

Comment: No its not a pattern, just a teammate who asked me to rewrite his question. Can you think of what actually happened?

Comment: You mentioned that the CreatedDate changed on the `RecordType` records. That would suggest they also have new ID's.

Comment: @DanielBallinger, Yes this is true that custom object has new ids. As same record types were also present in the older version, why this happened? Is it a platform bug or we did something wrong?

Comment: Check this: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/290451/77736 maybe it could help you on solve the problem