# Spring 20 An error occurred while trying to update the record

Tags: case, aura, component

Over the weekend our sandbox was updated to the Spring 20 release.

We have a custom Aura component which is used to create cases. When attempting to submit a case after the release update we see the following error:

> An error occurred while trying to update the record. Please try again.
>   Record Type ID: this ID value isn't valid for the user: `012000000000000AAA`

Testing with the same details and code in a Winter 20 sandbox works fine. All of the users used in the test have full access to the object and all of it's record types.

Is anyone else experiencing the same problem or have any indication of what could be causing this problem?

P.s. the component uses standard recordEditForm tags

Comment: There seems to be some issue with Record types. https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/287806/upgrade-of-unlocked-package-changed-recordtypeid-of-existing-records Salesforce might be fixing it.

Comment: can you add your lightning component code where you used `recordEditForm`

Comment: If you found this question because you have the same issue, **please do not write an answer unless you have a solution or clear information to add**. Please don't add an answer to say that you're also affected by the same problem.

Comment: Facing the similar issue. Salesforce Case has been logged.

Comment: I believe this is due to : https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring20/release-notes/rn_networks_guest_sharing_security_alert.htm

Comment: @Hamza has making changes regarding that update rectified the problem? We are still experiencing issues

Comment: @Salesf0rce No, still waiting for SF Support to suggest solution/workaround

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have resolved this issue.
In aura component or lwc, when we have a  if we don't specify a recordTypeId we receive the error specified:

> An error occurred while trying to update the record. Please try again. Record Type ID: this ID value isn't valid for the user: 012000000000000AAA

So if no recordTypeId was specified in the component an exception is thrown (*only in Spring '20, in our prod environment all works fine without the recordTypeId specified*)

We forced each lightning component to have a recordTypeId dinamically based on our business logic and the issue is solved for us.

```
<lightning:recordEditForm aura:id="form"
                          recordId="{!v.quoteId}"
                          recordTypeId="{!v.recordTypeId}"
                          onsubmit="{!c.handleSubmit}"
                          onsuccess="{!c.handleSuccess}"
                          objectApiName="Quote"
                          onerror="{!c.handleError}"
                          density="comfy">
```

**recordTypeId** is a variable where we return dinamically the recordTypeId we need.

After that fix we can create all records like in our production environment with the correct configuration.

Comment: Thanks @marzobryant90. We've tested with your solution and it has fixed the problem.

Comment: For anyone waiting on this issue, it has now been fixed by Salesforce via an emergency release.

Answer (score 1):

We are encountering the same issue with an aura component using the `lightning:recordEditForm` tags. Our prod environment is on Winter '20 and it works just fine but the sandboxes are Spring '20 and we get that exact error:

> *An error occurred while trying to update the record. Please try again. Record Type ID: this ID value isn't valid for the user:
>   012000000000000AAA*

Edit:

We have heard back from support with an estimated release for the fix being within a week (01/17/20). If not by then, they state that the likelihood of this being resolved before the Production roll out of Spring '20 is very high as this is affecting a large number of customers.

Comment: did you create ticket for spring20 know issue?

Comment: I have raised a case with Salesforce which has been escalated to the development team. Will update this question when there is some progress

Answer (score 1):

this is #spring20 know issue you can track it and work around also here [Know issue](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A000000KQeHQAW)